# Can we animate RecyclerView row item height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I know `RecyclerView` animates item additions/deletions for us for free. Is it supposed to support animating item height changes as well?

**For example** : Consider a row item with the following xml :-

```
<LineaLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I set "tv2" visibility to `View.VISIBLE`, the row height changes without any animation.

I've seen a few approaches of attempting to run your own `ValueAnimator` on the view itself, but my understanding is that it is

(1) not efficient

(2) you shouldn't run animations directly on the views themselves as they may get recycled from user interaction while the animation is running.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `visibility` component to your object that you're using in your adapter. In the item view's `onClickListener`, change the state of that object's visibility component depending on the current state. In the `onBindViewHolder`, set the visibility of `tv2` depending on the state of your object and notify the adapter that the object has changed.

Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyObject obj = myObjects.get(position);
    holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2).setVisibility(obj.isVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            obj.setVisible(!obj.isVisible());
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the `LinearLayout` in XML

Comment: This may cause some overlapping at first when the view becomes visible

Comment: @NathanReline could you please describe why?

Comment: @NathanReline same problem: animateLayoutChanges cause overlapping rows